To obtain the minimum value of $\frac{36}{a}+\frac{a}{b}$ given that $a+b = 9$ and $a>0, b>0$
I have read the answer that said it should apply the inequality $a+b\geq2\sqrt{ab}$, but the whole thing has to be rewritten as $\frac{4(a+b)}{a}+\frac{a}{b}$ to get the answer, which is $8$. This is where I don't understand why this rewriting step is mandatory to get the right answer regardless of its convenience in the calculation because when I applied the inequality to the original form, it didn't give the right answer. Could someone help me? Thanks a lot!
The process is:
$$\frac{4(a+b)}{a}+\frac{a}{b} = 4 + 4\times\frac{b}{a}+\frac{a}{b}$$
Then, apply the inequality $a+b\geq2\sqrt{ab}$ to $\left(4\times\frac{b}{a}+\frac{a}{b}\right)$, which is the last two items of the above, so the minimum value of their sum is 4; thus, the answer is $4+4 = 8$
What I was thinking is directly apply the inequality to  $\frac{36}{a}+\frac{a}{b}$, so $ \frac{36}{a}+\frac{a}{b} \geq 2\sqrt{\frac{36}{b}}$, and $a+b = 9$ and also if you want $ \frac{36}{a}+\frac{a}{b}$ to equal to its minimum value which is  $2\sqrt{\frac{36}{b}}$ it has to be that $\frac{36}{a} = \frac{a}{b}$, so there are two conditions for $b$ and $a$, which can be used to obtain the value of $b$. However, it does not give the right answer at the end.

From how to ask a good question: "Your question should be clear without the title.
After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

One simple pattern that one may use is $x + \frac{1}{x} \geq 2$ for $x >0$ Once  you reach $4 + 4\times\frac{b}{a}+\frac{a}{b}$  you can substitute  $ a = 2c$    to get to $4 + 2 \left( \frac{b}{c}  + \frac{c}{b}  \right)$  which is at least $4 + 2 \cdot 2$

The problem with your attempt is that you are equating both numbers $\frac{36}a$ and $\frac ab$ for the minimum value of the sum $\left(\frac{36}a+\frac ab\right)$ even if the product $\left(\frac{36}a\cdot\frac ab=\frac{36}b\right)$ is not constant, i.e., it is dependent on the variables.
The sum of two or more numbers becomes minimum at their equality only if their product is constant, as in the first approach where the product $\left(\frac{4b}a\cdot\frac ab=4\right)$ is not dependent on $a$ and $b$. In this case, the sum $\left(\frac{4b}a+\frac ab\right)$ assumes the minimum possible value when $\frac{4b}a=\frac ab$, i.e., $a=2b$. So, $a+b=3b=9\implies b=3,\ a=6$. Hence, the minimum value is $6+2=8$.
To learn how it works, recall a fundamental algebraic identity:
$$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2=(a-b)^2+4ab=(a-b)^2+(2\sqrt{ab})^2$$
It is clear that $(a+b)$ becomes minimum when $a=b$ for the given product $ab$ (constant). It also shows one of the most fundamental and useful inequalities $\frac{a+b}2\geq\sqrt{ab}$ (AM–GM inequality).
Hope this helps!

Thanks for the clarification!

You're most welcome!

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
\begin{align}
\dfrac{36}{a}+\dfrac{a}{b}
&= \dfrac{36}{a}+\dfrac{a+b}{b}-1\\
&=\dfrac{36}{a}+\dfrac{9}{b}-1\\
&=\dfrac{6^2}{a}+\dfrac{3^2}{b}-1\\
&\ge\dfrac{(6+3)^2}{a+b}-1=\dfrac{9^2}{9}-1=9-1=8,
\end{align} which is the desired minimum value that you showed.


Minimize $~\displaystyle \frac{36}{a} + \frac{a}{b}~$ 
given that $~0 < a,b,~$ and $~(a + b) = 9.~$

Normally, I would defer providing the following answer, because it is off-topic to the specific question of the original poster.  However, the answer of Pustam Raut directly answers the original poster's question, so I consider it open season to provide what I regard as a simpler approach.
By simpler approach, I intend that all that is required is to create a single variable function $~f(a),~$ compute $~f'(a),~$ and then analyze the behavior of $~f'(a)~$ to determine the behavior of $~f(a)~$ in the interval $~0 < a < 9.$
The posted question did not specify precalculus.  Further, my understanding (which could be mistaken) is that Cauchy-Schwarz is a topic in real analysis (AKA calculus).  While it does seem reasonable for the problem composer to provide this problem as a way of learning how to apply Cauchy-Schwarz, it also seems to me that the problem is more simply attacked  by examining $~f'(a).$

From the problem constraints, you can specify
$$f(a) = \frac{36}{a} + \frac{a}{9 - a} = \frac{324 - 36a + a^2}{9a - a^2} = \frac{(a - 18)^2}{9a - a^2},~$$
and use the first derivative of $~f(a)~$ to examine the behavior of $~f(a)~$ in the interval $~0 < a < 9.$
Now, you can use the chain rule that
$$\frac{d}{dx} \left[ ~\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} ~\right] = \frac{g(x)f'(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{[ ~g(x) ~]^2}$$
to compute
$$f'(a) = \frac{[ ~( ~9a - a^2~)(2)(a - 18) ~] - [ ~(a-18)^2 (9 - 2a) ~]}{\left[ ~9a-a^2 ~\right]^2}$$
$$= \frac{a - 18}{\left[ ~9a-a^2 ~\right]^2} \times \left\{ ~[ ~18a - 2a^2 ~] - [ ~( ~a - 18)(9 - 2a) ~] ~\right\}. \tag1 $$
Let
$$g(a) = [ ~18a - 2a^2 ~] - [ ~( ~a - 18)(9 - 2a) ~]$$
$$= [ ~18a - 2a^2 ~] - [ ~9a - 162 - 2a^2 + 36a]$$
$$= -27a + 162 = 27 \times (6 - a).$$
Then,
$$f'(a) = \frac{a - 18}{\left[ ~9a-a^2 ~\right]^2} \times g(a)$$
$$= \frac{a - 18}{\left[ ~9a-a^2 ~\right]^2} \times 27 \times (6 - a). \tag2 $$
For $~0 < a < 9, ~$ in the first fraction on the RHS of (2) above, the numerator is always negative, and the denominator is always positive.  Further, the expression $~(6 - a)~$ is positive for $~a < 6,~$ zero for $~a = 6,~$ and negative for $~a > 6.~$
Therefore,

$f'(a) < 0~$ for $~a < 6.$

$f'(a) = 0~$ for $~a = 6.$

$f'(a) > 0~$ for $~a > 6.$


Therefore,

$f(a)~$ is strictly decreasing for $~a < 6.$

$f(a)~$ obtains a minimum value at $~a = 6.$

$f(a)~$ is strictly increasing for $~a > 6.$


So, the minimum value of $~f(a)~$ in the interval $~0 < a < 9~$ is
$$f(6) = \frac{36}{6} + \frac{6}{9 - 6} = 8.$$
